# PHP MySQL optimal way to perform multiple dependent queries

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysqli

I need to query (read) some data, and analyze it before performing another query (read) on a different table.

I've looked at [mysqli multiple statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) but they don't have documentation for situations where the second query depends on the result of the first query.

It seems my current code of doing two queries might not be optimal. Is there a more optimal way to do this?

```
//FIRST QUERY
$query1= "SELECT color FROM products WHERE type = '$productType';";
$result = $conn->query($query1);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $colorProduct = $row["color"];
    }
} 


//ANALYZE SEARCH RESULT FROM FIRST QUERY
if ($colorProduct == "green") {
    $colorType = "greenColorType";
}   
//a lot more analysis


//SECOND QUERY
$query2 = "SELECT price FROM Vendors WHERE color = '$colorType';";
$result2 = $conn->query($query2);

if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $priceOfProduct = priceOfProduct . $row["price"];
    }
} 

$conn->close();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd be tempted to create a stored procedure for this - especially if the processing is a regular task. The last query is using `.` ~ presumably this is for addition so you would probably want `+` instead?

Comment: It looks like you could do this with a single query

Comment: I'd agree that this can be done with a single query. The thing that I guess stumps me about this is that `$colorType` is only set if `$colorProduct == "green"`. Are you sure that this is what you want? Perhaps state explicitly what you're trying to achieve, as your code is difficult to interpret in it's current state.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you join those 2 queries into one and analyse later if you need to. For example:

```
"SELECT price FROM products
JOIN Vendors ON Vendors.color = products.color
WHERE type = $productType
AND color = 'green';"
```

MySQL is declarative language so it is usually better to "tell it" what you want and than modify data afterwards (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to add a "and" to the "where" clause : SELECT color FROM products WHERE type = '$productType' and color = 'green'

Then you have to join or to add a sub query in SQL.

In fact, you should do only one SQL request.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your color values in the vendors table all have ColorType added after the actual colour name, which you are dealing with in PHP, before making a second query.

Mysql can do this for you. Here's an example:

```
"SELECT a.color, b.price FROM products a, vendors b WHERE a.type = '$productType' AND a.color = SUBSTR(b.color,1,LENGTH(a.color);"
```

The `WHERE` clause specifies a match on your `$productType` variable with the type column of table a (products) and a match between the color value in table a and the beginning of the color value in table b. It uses the `LENGTH` statement to match regardless of the length of the color in table a. So if color in table a is `darkblue` and table b is `darkblueColorType` it will match, and if the values are `red` and `redColorType` it will still match.